# Intent entre cardview kotlin

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin, android-intent, cardview

Buenos días tengo un problema para pasar datos entre mis distintos activity con cardview. Mi app se podria dividir del siguiente modo:

Activity A.1:

Se compone de un activity con un cardview donde manejo un JSON.

Activity A.2:

Es el adaptador del cardview A.1 y donde obtengo la posicion y los datos elegidos por el usuario y mediante un intent soy capaz de mandarlo y recogerlo al activity B.1.

Activity B.1:

Se compone de un activity con un cardview donde manejo otro JSON y hasta aqui soy capaz de pasar los datos del activity A.2.

Activity B.2:

Este es el adaptador del cardview de B.1 y aqui el intent llega vacio.

Activity C:

Es donde debo recoger la información de los activity anteriores para realizar los calculos. Soy capaz de mandar los datos del activity B.2 y recogerlos en el activity C pero los datos de A.2 se pierden por el camino...

Espero haberme explicado correctamente ya que estoy empezando a programar desde hace muy poco y sobre todo gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de datos quieres pasar? ¿Tiene que ser en respuesta a un evento como una acción del usuario?

Comment: Son datos de tipo string. Si los lanzo junto con el evento onclicklidtener del item del cardview no hay problema. El problema esta es que pierdo el contenido del intent al pasar de b1 a su adapter b2. Quizas si paso el codigo seria mas sencillo?